# fetch() function is not working in methods

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-for

I am trying to retrieve data from REST API. I got below code from a tutorial which are not working in my machine but working in that video.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Articles</h2>

        <div class="card mb-2" v-for="article in articles" v-bind:key="article.id">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{ article.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ article.body }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                articles : [],
                article : {
                    id : '',
                    title : '',
                    body : ''
                },
                article_id : '',
                pagination : {},
                edit : false
            }
        },

        created(){
            this.fetchArticles();
        },

         methods:{
             fetchArticles(){
                 fetch('api/articles')
                     .then(res => res.json())
                     .then(res => {
                         this.arcticles = res.data;
                         console.log(res.data);
                     })
             }
         }

    }
</script>
```

After few research I changed my code to

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Articles</h2>

        <div class="card mb-2" v-for="article in articles" v-bind:key="article.id">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{ article.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ article.body }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                articles : [],
                article : {
                    id : '',
                    title : '',
                    body : ''
                },
                article_id : '',
                pagination : {},
                edit : false
            }
        },

        created(){
            axios
                .get('api/articles')
                .then(res => {
                    this.articles = res.data.data;
                    console.log(res.data.data);
                })
        },
    }
</script>
```

and it's working fine.

I want to fix the previous code (from the tutorial). Otherwise I'll not get further lessons.

Comment: I think it should be `@{{ article.title }}`

Comment: @STA Not working

Comment: what do you mean "not working" What's the error message?

Comment: @wschopohl Not getting any error. The article list is not showing.

Comment: what happens if you add .catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
}); after the second then after fetch? So fetch().then().then().catch()

Comment: @wschopohl tried your code, no error. I think `res.data` is returning an empty array. That's why there is nothing in list.

Comment: so when you do: console.log("result", res.data); you see at least the "result" ?

Comment: @wschopohl In console the result is showing perfectly.

Comment: Puh, what if you change your second res to data like: .then(data => {
                         this.arcticles = data.data;
                         console.log(data.data);
                     })

Comment: @wschopohl `Error: ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

From MDN documentation, the json() method is implemented on Response body, and it returns a promise wich resolves to result of parsing the body text as json.

```
response.json().then(data => {
  // do something with your data
});
```

So, when using in fetch, the correct syntax is:

```
fetchArticles(){
                 fetch('api/articles')
                     .then(res => res.json())
                     .then(data=> {
                         this.arcticles = data;  // the result here contains only the json data, it is not a response object, so it does not have a 'data' property.
                         console.log(data);
                     })
             }
```